# Error implementing a struct constructor in C

Tags: c, struct, constructor

I get this error from trying to implement a constructor with a struct in C. I do not understand as I follow what I read online

```
#170 a function type is not allowed here
```

Here is the struct definition.

```
typedef struct ConnectionTestResults_t {

        ConnectionError_t detectedErrors;
        bool isTempShorted;
        bool isRespShorted;
        int8_t conn1ShortedPins[2];
        int8_t conn2ShortedPins[2];
        int8_t spo21ShortedPins[2];
        int8_t spo22ShortedPins[2];
        int8_t usbShortedPins[2];
        int8_t conn1OpenPins[2];
        int8_t conn2OpenPins[2];
        int8_t spo21OpenPins[2];
        int8_t spo22OpenPins[2];
        int8_t usbOpenPins[2];
        ConnectionTestResults_t() {
            conn1ShortedPins = {-1,-1};
        }

} ConnectionTestResults_t;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Constructors are a C++ feature.

Comment: You can't have member functions in C. In C one rather have stand-alone non-member global functions which possibly create and then initialize structures.

Comment: And whatever tutorial you're following, it's either using the wrong language or is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constructors are a c++ (etc) thing, you would normally associated them with Object Oriented programming, which C is not.

If you wanted to, you could implement an initialisation function, something along the lines of;

```
function void someFunction(ConnectionTestResults_t * instance) {
   ...
}

function void initConnectionTestResult(ConnectionTestResults_t * ctr) {
  ctr->myFunc = &someFunction;
  ctr->initialisableValue = INITIAL_VALUE;
}
```

(apologies for syntax, been a while since I've done C programming)

If you wanted to implement something like OO methods, the closest you could reasonably come would be;

```
ConnectionTestResults_t thing;
initConnectionTestResult(&thing);
thing.myFunc(&thing);
```

Including a type field, and switching on that is another way of achieving it.

```
if (thing->isAFoo) {
  fooIt(&thing);
} else {
  barIt(&thing);
}
```

but consider if that's the right way of achieving your objective first.

Comment: I though it would be clean to make the constructor a return function, so instead of passing by reference, there are no arguments and thing = init(). Would you think it is favorable to use your approach, less memory used, or whatever? Thanks

Comment: It depends what entity you want to manage the memory. If you do `thing = init()` thing must live on the heap (i.e. you `malloc` it inside `init`), otherwise it would live on the stack, and (probably) overwritten when init returns! That can constrain your design when you need to ensure it gets de-allocated - what unit of code has that repsonsibility?

If you instead pass by ref, you can have the thing on stack or heap, as appropriate.